# Correct use of the term “Taxa de Natalidade”

Tags: american-english, translation, portuguese

I have received the answer from my teacher saying that the term “Fertility Rate” is not suitable for the context.
The context is this,

> The increase in life expectancy, concomitantly with a decreased `fertility rate`...

What is the suitable term in this context?

Comment: Is this an exercise in translation into English from the original Portuguese? If so I would have thought that "birth rate" was a much more accurate translation  than 'fertility rate'.

Comment: I would remind you that this is an English language site. I assume that your term is Spanish, in which case it is "translation" that you need in your title, and you should provide dictionary definitions of the individual words or explain what the phrase implies.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for a translation of a Spanish term.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It’s Portuguese, not Spanish. It just means birth rate.

Comment: *Concomitantly* needs a verb. It would be *concomitant* here, except it is the wrong word. Concomitance involves the idea of "naturally occurring together". That isn't the case here. I think you just want to say "along with".

Comment: If what you need is a clarification of a teacher's comment on your homework, why don't you ask the teacher who made the comment? It is a part of a teacher's job to answer such follow-up questions from the students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Birth rate* is correct — *see*, for example, the [Cambridge Dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/birth-rate):

> **Birth rate** the number of births that happen during a period of time in a particular place

The number of births per unit time (e.g. per year) is a *rate* (*see*, for example, [the definition in Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rate?src=search-dict-box)).

> **Rate** 1 a : a quantity, amount, or degree of something measured per
> unit of something else

(I would say Merriam Webster’s “something else“ should be *time*.)

As a biological scientist, I would say that your original “fertility rate” is scientifically incorrect, as [fertility is a state](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fertility):

> **Fertility** the quality or state of being fertile

However *fertility* it is misused by the media to mean *birth rate*, as reflected in the second entry for Merriam Webster.

One diminishes the power of the English language to discriminate between objects and ideas by accepting this sort of misuse†. However, if you really must, the logically correct form of this would be *fertility* without the *rate*.

---

† A decrease in the birthrate can be caused by a number of factors, including increased use of contraception, lower frequency of sexual intercourse, and decreased fertility. Fertility would be measured by the frequency of pregnancy resulting from sexual intercourse when other factors have been controlled.

Comment: Thanks. Will change. Just say what is right. Don't like to criticize teachers anyway, as students can get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The term *fertility rate* is in widespread use when discussing demography and matters of population. It is an acceptable term. Because the full context of your question is not clear, your teacher may still be correct, but not because *fertility rate*" itself is wrong.

Here is one convincing example of the use of the term in an international organisation:

"The total *fertility rate* in a specific year is defined as the total number of children that would be born to each woman if she were to live to the end of her child-bearing years and give birth to children in alignment with the prevailing age-specific *fertility rates*. It is calculated by totalling the age-specific *fertility rates* as defined over five-year intervals. Assuming no net migration and unchanged mortality, a total *fertility rate* of 2.1 children per woman ensures a broadly stable population. Together with mortality and migration, fertility is an element of population growth, reflecting both the causes and effects of economic and social developments. The reasons for the dramatic decline in birth rates during the past few decades include postponed family formation and child-bearing and a decrease in desired family sizes. This indicator is measured in children per woman."

From [OECD Data](https://data.oecd.org/pop/fertility-rates.htm)